# React-router with Saga Server-side render redirect

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, redux-saga, server-side-rendering

The issue is that I have an initial fetch request that gets the query string from the URL and makes a request to get a specified product page.

The same logic and routing is used on the client side and server side.

The API request gets executed in `redux-saga`, but, when it fails (no matching product), the site is already on the `/product` route, and so redirect needs to happen.

On the client-side this is very easy, as it can be redirected dynamically using `browserHistory` or just `window.location.href`, but on the server, i would have to pass down the `res` object and use `res.redirect` and, possibly, use two different redirect functions with this approach.

The other solution is to catch this in a topmost fashion; on express index.js during  `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component)`, and also on the client side endpoint when it fails - with different logic. For example, a 404 view with express redirect. But, because `saga` is not the topmost in hierarchy anyway, throwing this 404 and catching it in the uppermost context (express server) requires passing it up and up in a very "dirty" try/catch way.

Any suggestions how to tackle that in terms of correctness? I really don't want to have routing logic doubled up on express side, so I'd rather have it handled nicely with isomorphic code.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably exposing your main state to be picked up by the front-end code. Any calls that are returned from sagas can update that state. We are using a `set404()` and `set301()` actions when redux saga does not return the data we want. These actions are triggered and they set `return404: true` or `return301: true` in the main state object. So before rendering our app to string we inspect that object. If any of these are present we return a relevant response from the server.